# Why are Request parameters flashed in html before redirect?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, redis

I have a Laravel (PHP 8.2) project running on a server with docker compose with containers for each app, php, mysql, redis.

When initially running these containers, my app works fine and I can login from anywhere. However after some time has past (maybe an hour or two) any device that wasn't logged in now can't. Upon any submission I get a flash of my request parameters on the screen (not in the url as this is a post request) Showing this
"_token= username= password= Redirecting to mydomain.com" which lasts for less than a second before being redirected back to the login page.

If I restart the containers I can login fine (no parameters flashed) until time has passed. Why on Earth would this be happening?

I tried switching from using File session to Redis.
I made sure my .env has the correct domain set in the APP_URL
I made sure my redis container was persistent by adding a volume
I made sure my server was not hitting its resource bandwidth

When debugging my LoginController my app successfully authenticates my user but after the first redirect my session data is lost and the user is not longer authenticated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Set APP_DEBUG=false in env. Also debug the code that is handling the auth part . Search in allproject for those words Redirecting etc..

Answer (score 0):

So after tons of research and asking ChatGPT I finally found something suspicious taking up all my CPU usage. I was hosting this application in a docker compose setup and was exposing a port on my php container to the world. This allowed for two malicious processes named "kdevtmpfsi" and "kinsing" which are associated with crypto mining to be injected. Simply put, nginx was acting strange due to over usage in my resources and all I needed to do was ensure my php container was only available locally.